# A function to pick a value from a table or data frame

Tags: r

```
CROP_CODE_MODEL WWHT WBAR SBAR WBEA SBEA WPOT WOSR SOSR LNSE DPEA SBEE SETA
NFERT_AMT        51   61   66   71   76   81   86   91   96  101  106  111
NFERT_PRICE      1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
PFERT_AMT        51   61   66   71   76   81   86   91   96  101  106  111
PFERT_PRICE      1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
KFERT_AMT        51   61   66   71   76   81   86   91   96  101  106  111
KFERT_PRICE      1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

I have the data below and I am trying to write a function so that when I supply the crop name and the input name the corresponding value can be picked or selected.

For example I want write something like

```
Nfertamt <- function(crop, Nfert)
```

so that  "wheat" and "Nfertiliser", the corresponding value for "WWHT" and "NFERT_AMT" (51) will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function, you just need to subset the row and column you want:

```
my.data["NFERT_AMT","WWHT"]
```

As in:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20)
> df[3, 2]
> [1] 13
```